# How to use twitter Oauth Token to set up cookies

Tags: javascript, ios, twitter, web, twitter-oauth

I have a iOS application. Inside my application, I implemented twitter share function, which was implemented by using twitter OAuth access token and access secure. I can do twitter post through twitter api by using OAuth access token and access secure.

However, I want to have a UIWebview to access twitter.com to let user to see their twitter account activities. However, I don't want to ask user to sign in again through webview. I have already got all OAuth information, is there a way I can manually set up twitter cookie by using those info.